# Xamarin.Android app runs fine on Xamarin Android Player, won't run on my device. "Deployment failed. Internal error."

Tags: android, xamarin.android

When I try to deploy the app to my device the compiler gives me the following error with no other information: Deployment failed. Internal error.

After doing some research I'm pretty confident that the problem is either with my Android Build configurations or some conflicting file names.

I attached a screenshot of the [developer options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLUMt.png) on my device, and the [Android Build options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtS01.png) in Xamarin Studio. I can provide other details and screenshots too.

Any suggestions on what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete your app from device and then try to deploy again.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, BUT I thought just because the app didn't appear with my other apps anymore it was already uninstalled. I went to the apps menu in settings and, sure enough, I found it still there! I uninstalled it from there and now it works!

Comment: Yes, it can be sometimes